# how to access one google app with another google app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I have one google app engine applicaion(app1) and I want to access it from another google app engine applicaion(app2).
I do not want install two separate apps. I want to one app within another app. 
While installing app2 how can i assign scopes of app2 to app1 for that domain.? 
can anyone guide for this me ..?

Comment: What do you mean by "google app" ? A Google App Engine application ? A Google Apps for Business domain ?

Comment: A google app engine applicaion.

Comment: Please edit your question tor reflect this, explain clearly your use case (for example why your need two applications).

Right now I do not think people will be able to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: You may want to look into pp engine modules.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [app engine modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). In general, I'd recommend learning more about what app engine is, how it works, etc... your question is very vague and almost doesn't make sense. You want one app within another app? I am confused. I hope this answers your question.